# Pointer to bit in port register

Tags: c, pointers, bit

I have some code that needs to run on 2 different PCBs. At bootup the code does detect/know on which hardware it runs and sets a flag.

Now, some signals change ports depending on the hardware, i.e.:
on HW1, signal A is on 0x08 on P9 whereas it is on 0x02 on P14 on the other hardware.

I can easily check the flag everywhere signal A is used - however this solution does not seem 'nice' to me.

I can also easily change the port at boot with something like this:

```
if(cIsHW1) Reg = &P14;         
      else Reg = &P9;
```

and use Reg to access the correct port on each HW.

However, how do I change the bit position as well? I now there is no such thing as a pointer to a bit in a register - which is actually what would I think I would need.

I need to read these port bits and set/clear it as well.

Do I miss something or do I really need to check the flag (if .. else) everywhere I need to access that port bit?

Thanks
McL

Comment: Even if you *could* have a pointer to a single bit, how would you else check it without an `if` statement?

Comment: By using a bit mask, say `if(cIsHW1) mask = 0x02; else mask = 0x08;` and then read the port bit with `Reg & mask` which will be either `== 0` or `!= 0`.

Comment: Use the bit-shift operators. Setting: `var |= (1<<bitnum)`, reading: `res = (var >> bitnum)&1`

Comment: Thank you guys ... that's going into direction I was hoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect the hardware-dependent data in a structure, and figure out which one to use at startup:

```
struct hw_config {
  volatile uint32_t *reg;
  uint32_t mask;
} boardA = { .reg = &P14, .mask = 8 },
  boardB = { .reg = &P9,  .mask = 2 },
  * board;

int main(void)
{
  // Figure out which board we're on, and set the board pointer.
  board = running_on_board_a() ? &boardA : boardB;

  // Example usage.
  *board->reg |= board->mask;
}
```

If you can figure out which one to use at compile-time, you can of course optimize this by never defining the redundant one.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea if this would be faster than have the classic if-else for the decision which define to pick? ... I actually think so.

Comment: @McLion That depends. This approach will lead to extra memory accesses to load the register and masks, instead of being able to inline them in the instruction stream, but on the other hand there will be no jumps.

Comment: Thanks. ... still fighting with it: HWcur->TXreg |= HWcur->mask; returns invalid |= operand ... something with my Pxy pointer to the register is still wrong.

Comment: @McLion You might need an asterisk, I did. Also I shouldn't use the `register` keyword like that.

Comment: I already changed the register ;-) compiler would not accept it.

Comment: Perfect! Works a charm .. and learned something more!
Thanks a million.